# How can I render the Index view of a controller without Index in the URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Login controller with an Index view that I want rendered at the url http://sitename/login. It works with I browse to http://sitename/login/index but I want to omit index from the URL. Here's my route config (default):

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboards", action = "Dashboard_1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

.. and the controller:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    // GET: Login
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had left the `Default` route alone, it would do what you ask. You just have to set the default value for the `action` route value as `Index`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Alternatively, you can insert an additional route to cover your Login controller.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    url: "login/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Dashboards", action = "Dashboard_1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

A third option is to rename your `LoginController.Index` method to `LoginController.Dashboard_1`, since that is your default action name for *every* controller in the application.